# How to substract Commission amount from the total price in sale.order.form in odoo16

Tags: python, xml, pycharm, odoo, odoo-16

[image]

I want to substarct commission 8 from total amount12. How to do this in odoo16. which function should need to override to achive this.

[image]

I overridden _compute_amounts() method. but the it donot reflect in the sale.order.form. Help me to solve this.